# Tic Tac Toe Can't change innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Everything I try to change the innerHTML on doesn't change anything. There are no X's or O's and the current players name doesn't display. I've been trying to figure this out. I've searched for an answer and from what I can tell everything I'm doing is the way I'm supposed to do it. I have to hand this in tonight, and I have to at least get the basics working so I can add some style.

```
function start() 
        {
            //alert("start");
            player1name = prompt("Enter First Player's Name", "");
            player2name = prompt("Enter Second Player's Name", "");
            currentPlayer = player1name;
            documet.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " 
                            choose a square.";

        }
```

Then I have all of my HTML.

```
<body onload="start()">

    <!--HEADING AND PLAYER NAME-->
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

    <!--DISPLAY NAME OF CURRENT PLAYER ON THEIR MOVE-->
    <h2 id="player"></h2>

    <!--TABLE-->
    <div class="Table">

        <!--FIRST ROW-->
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell" id="1" onclick="playerMoved(this, 1)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="2" onclick="playerMoved(this, 2)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="3" onclick="playerMoved(this, 4)"></div>    
        </div>

        <!--SECOND ROW-->
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell" id="4" onclick="playerMoved(this, 8)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="5" onclick="playerMoved(this, 16)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="6" onclick="playerMoved(this, 32)"></div>    
        </div>

        <!--THIRD ROW-->
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell" id="7" onclick="playerMoved(this, 64)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="8" onclick="playerMoved(this, 128)"></div>
            <div class="Cell" id="9" onclick="playerMoved(this, 256)"></div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2):

On this line

```
documet.getElementById("player").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
```

correct the spelling of 'document'

Comment: Hallelujah! I'm a horrible speller. It's hard keeping up with the instructors sometimes, then you just copy paste everything wrong. Sheesh. Should have asked sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your entire code but is it because you write "documet" instead of "document" ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo: `documet.getElementById` needs to be `document.getElementById`